# Get sum of payments grouped by payment type

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, orm, eloquent

`SELECT payment_type, sum(total_received) FROM payments GROUP BY payment_type`

In MySQL gives me a nice list of all my payment types together with my totals for that type.

-

`Payment::all()->groupBy('payment_type')->sum('total_received')`

in Eloquent gives me absolutely nothing.

What is the Eloquent equivalent to the above MySQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best would be using `lists`, since returning Model with just 2 properties that you want, is redundant:

```
Payment::selectRaw('payment_type as type, sum(total_received) as sum')
   ->groupBy('type')
   ->lists('sum', 'type');

// returns array, something like this:
array(
  'type1' => '25',
  'type2' => '50',
  ...
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code block that will work in Eloquent:

```
$var = DB::table('payments')
                 ->select('payment_type', DB::raw('sum(total_received)'))
                 ->groupBy('payment_type')
                 ->get();
```